# JPlayer - How to make the audio player responsive?

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, jplayer

is there a way to make jplayer responsive? It's this skin:
http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-01-supplied-mp3/?theme=0

I would like to scale the whole player using percentage on Width. I tried with a wrapper:

```
.wrapper {

max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: 100%\0/; /* IE8 hack for max-width */
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Can anybody help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I came across this jplayer responsive design today, which might point you in the right direction:

Demo:
http://www.beyondhyper.com/jplayer/

GitHub:
https://github.com/BeyondHyper/responsive-jPlayer

Answer (score 2):

I use the following to make jplayer responsive. Jplayer adds style tags directly to the HTML so you need to use !important.

I'm having trouble with responsive video still though as jquery sets the video height and width to zero before play is pressed, if you set the height to auto on video in CSS it will display the poster on top of the video on first load. This should work fine for audio though

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {

    /* jplayer */
    .jp-video video, .jp-audio, .jp-controls-holder {
        width: 100% !important;
    }

   .jp-video, .jp-video > div, .jp-video img {
       height: auto !important;
       width: 100% !important;
   }

   .jp-video-360p {
       max-width: 570px !important;
   }

   .jp-video-270p {
       max-width: 480px !important;
   }

   .jp-progress {
       width: 130px;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The player you specified has a static width set on it's container, div.jp-audio. It's set to 420px. Try changing that value or commenting it out. I think that is what you are looking for. If not, let me know.

Comment: did anyone get this working i tried the above suggestion with the wrapper but no joy, I've set the width to 80% for the player but when looking on a 320 phone the progress and some of the controls are outside the box

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the wrapper's width 100% and the max-width whatever you want it limited to.

```
.wrapper {
max-width: 420px;
width:100%;
}
```

I usually don't specify a height when making elements responsive.  Hope this helps

Comment: No, that doesn't work. As Derick said there are static widths in the player. I'm afraid there's no other way than making all static elements flexible (giving them % values). I was looking for a "wrapper" solution that scales the whole player with all the static elements in it, but I think there is no such solution....

Comment: The question implies that you are making a fully responsive jplayer so I just assumed the rest of the elements within the wrapper will be styled accordingly.  Of course everything inside will have to be adjusted.

Comment: I'm actually building a responsive jplayer at the moment.  I'll post somewhere when finished.  Definitely possible, jplayer is just really tedious css.

Answer (score 0):

This what you are looking for

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px)
#wrapper {
width: 65%;
float: left;
margin: 30px auto auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just created a gist with my work:
https://gist.github.com/ishahak/d76d46ce1423f86982366ac325f5b59d

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way to make JWplayer 5 responsive, it is meant for videos, but it works with audios as well. http://www.miracletutorials.com/how-to-make-jw-player-5-10-responsive/

Basically, what you need to do is to set 2 wrapper divs:

```
   <div style='position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;padding-bottom:56.25%;'>
   <div style='position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;'>
embedding code...
    </div>
    </div>
```

Then set the width and the height for embedding code of the player to 100%
In the first line, you see padding-bottom:56.25%, this is a value for the height of a HD video. For an audio, you will want to make this much smaller, unless you want to show a poster image.
I hope this helps?

Comment: JWPlayer is not JPlayer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I indeed thought this was about JWplayer.
However, it is still worthwhile to try, only takes a minute to find out.